# AJAX and PHP; not passing the variables or not working?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, variables

I'm making an administrative interface for a semester project app.

Our last duty is to make an admin page. I've set up everything an admin should have access to (updating user info, deleting a user, resetting stats, etc etc) except for the most important one: Creating a new user.

When I input the data to create the user, nothing new shows up in the data base. Tried it with a standard query (no variables, you'll see below) and still nothing went through leading me to believe that it is not accessing the variables at all.

My Javascript AJAX:

```
 function createNewUser()
 {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to create this user?") == true)
    {
    createNewUserAJAX();
    }
 }



 function createNewUserAJAX()
 {
      var fName = document.getElementById('ADDFirstName').value;
  var lName = document.getElementById('ADDLastName').value;
  var user = document.getElementById('ADDUserName').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('ADDPassword').value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById('ADDPassword2').value;
  var slateID = document.getElementById('ADDSlate').value;
  var keeperID = document.getElementById('ADDKeeper').value;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            alert(user+" created successfully!");
            toggleCreateUserInterface();
       }
   }

   if (password == password2)
   {
           xmlhttp.open("GET","AddUserAJAX.php?uname="+user+"&pwd="+password+"&slate="+slateID+"&keeper="+keeperID+"&fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
else
{
    alert("Passwords must match");
}
 }
```

The code on my ADDUserAJAX.php page:

```
<?php
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uname']);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pwd']);
$slateID = mysql__real_escape_string($_GET['slate']);
$keeperID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['keeper']);
$fName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fName']);
$lName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lName']);

mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
@mysql_select_db('slatekeeperdatabase') or die("Unable to select database");

$lastUserQuery = mysql_query("select max(userID) from users;");
$lastUserID = mysql_result($lastUserQuery,0);
$newUserID = $lastUserID+1;

$lastStatsQuery = mysql_query("select max(statsID) from stats;");
$lastStatsID = mysql_result($lastStatsQuery,0);
$newStatsID = $lastStatsID+1;


//$query= "INSERT INTO users VALUES (".$newUserID.", ".$fName.", ".$lName.", ".$pw.", ".$userName.", '', 1, 1000, 100, ".$slateID.", ".$keeperID.", ".$newStatsID.", 0)";
$query2 = "insert into users values (9, 'James','Lom', 'red','jlom4', '', 1, 1000, 100, 1, 1, 1, 0 );";
mysql_query($query2);




 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

$query variable is what I'm trying attempting to get through. $query2 was just test query to check if it was even passing at all (which it is not)

Any help is much appreciated. It's so strange because I got it working previously with the test data (never got it working with what I'm actually attempting to get through). Perhaps I put incorrect syntax somewhere that I cannot locate... (oh, POST will be used after everything gets working. Security isn't our primary concern at this point.)

Comment: Did you test the `ADDuserAJAX.php` using a browser?

Comment: i updated my answer can you check

Comment: @M.chaudhry have you tried using `encodeURIcomponent()` in JavaScript to generate the URL correctly? `var fName = encodeURIcomponent(document.getElementById('ADDFirstName').value);` and so on? I believe there's a problem in the URL generated by JavaScript, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use mysql_real_escape_string before making mysql connection. If there's no connection, mysql_real_escape_string won't do anything.

Comment: Didn't notice that, I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving Query fields to insert

```
$query2 = "insert into users (id, Name etc) values (9, 'James','Lom', 'red','jlom4', '', 1, 1000, 100, 1, 1, 1, 0 );";
```

i noticed `"".` in your $query2 remove this i think i can also be a error and second remove `;` in the kind of `)`

To debugg echo your `$query2` see what is missing and also try to run your query directly in database SQL

Comment: Did this before but I just tried this again and still nothing :(. Thank you, though.

Comment: you have to do this for inserting start debugging Echo Your $query2 see what is missing or the best way to print this SQuery 2 directing into database SQL  database errors will help you

Comment: EDIT: I got it to access the page with hard coded through debugging. Thank you. I've concluded that there is some error with my PHP variables on AddUserAJAX.php. I'll continue debugging.